# The word "urgent" in a title should trigger a warning

Tags: discussion, feature-request, titles, warnings

It doesn't currently, and it adds nothing to the question. Most of the time it's "urgent" because homework is due soon. Agree or disagree?

Comment: "Urgent" is one of those words that make me actively ignore a question. "No, your time is **not** more important than mine."

Comment: @J.M. Fully agreed.

Comment: If it triggers a warning, isn't it just helping the poster be cleverer in disguising a homework question? Whereas if there were no warning and the word was left in, *we* would know it was a homework question and we could close it. By the time the OP understands, it'd be too late (if indeed it was "urgent"). Of course, this depends on whether our aim is to be "ethical" and not answer homework questions as much as possible, or only to have to answer well written questions.

Comment: @M.Vinay I have no issue with homework questions and I don't think many people do. Low quality questions or homework questions with no effort shown, I do have a problem with and I routinely downvote/vote to close.

Comment: @ZacharySelk If the OP chooses to use the word "urgent", then the rest of the question is also most likely to be poorly typed, or at least to show no effort. See [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/can-we-ban-the-use-of-urgent?rq=1#comment54523_13800) too.

Comment: @M.Vinay That's why I want to offer a warning. Most of these questions are low quality. Hopefully a warning would get them to think first. Maybe...maybe not. We can at least try though.

Comment: @M. Vinay, As Zachary says, a warning will at least force them to pause. Certainly, it may or may not trigger a reconsideration on the part of the asker, but at least we have given them the opportunity.

Comment: @ZacharySelk: I apologize for the nuisance: I had deleted a tag without really understanding what role it played in the question. It wasn't a wise thing to do, so I rolled back to your original version. Once again, I apologize.

Comment: ur-gent adj. Requiring someone else to do my homework for me so I can go partying with my friends over the weekend.

Comment: Wonder why my comment was removed?

Comment: I certainly understand what you're saying, but I'm curious. Why spend time here, answering other people's questions, who may not even show appreciation for your efforts? @J.M.

Comment: Related: My [catalog of words that should generally not appear in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/retitling-questions-a-modest-proposal/8781#8781)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I agree. Right now there is a smallish list of words that will cause a warning to pop up when they appear in *short* question titles . From [Shog9's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17012) the regex is

> ```
> ^.{0,30}(^|\W)(anyone|difficult|doubt|easy|hard|help|interesting|please|problem|query|question|someone|stuck|very)(\W|$).{0,30}$
> ```

(Essentially a title containing at least one of the listed words and at most 30 characters before and at most 30 characters after matches the regex.)

Adding `urgent` to this list shouldn't be much of a problem.

This word doesn't actually appear in too many titles (using moderator abilities, only 61 questions on the site, deleted and undeleted, currently have this word in the title). However it is often a sign of a terrible question: only 10 of these questions remain on the site undeleted. Of course, this word is often edited out by other users, but according to [the SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/553579/questions-originally-posted-with-urgent-in-title), there are only 31 extant questions which were originally posted with "urgent" in the title.

Comment: Why are the words "question"/"query"/"problem" on the list?

Comment: @JohnMayne Because they are pretty much superfluous. Since one is asking a question, it's generally redundant to use "question" in the title. "Query" and "problem" are generally synonyms (though "problem" does have some technical uses). Not that these warnings do much. [Over 2700 undeleted questions asked this year currently have "question" in the title.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aquestion+created%3A2016) Another 800 have been deleted.

Comment: Any status on getting this done?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Site moderators cannot alter the site blacklists/warnings, so someone else will have to do it. I've pinged a CM linking specifically to this question, so someone should know about it. I don't think it is a difficult thing to do, but who knows when it'll get done. (It took about two years to get that [other feature request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17244) implemented.)

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it won't take 2 years...

Comment: @Zachary, well, [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) seems likely...

Comment: Hey, it's almost 2 years! Hahaha

Comment: @ZacharySelk Now there is some response from the moderators [at least in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2018/7/19).

Comment: @martin thank you for the update